# как работает это функция в реализации программы c++ решение систем нелинейный уравненией методом простой итерации

Tags: c++

`if (abs(xx-x)< e && abs(yy-y)< e) break;`

как работает это функция в реализации программы c++ решение систем нелинейный уравненией методом простой итерации 
e-это точность

не понимаю алгоритм ее работы

Comment: Если xx отличается от x меньше чем на e, а yy от y меньше чем на ту же величину - выйти из цикла...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сравнить обычные и дробные числа можно оператором `==`, но так как у дробных числах в c++ (float и double) ограниченная точность, то это может повлечь за собой ошибки, поэтому вводится константа e или eps, которая обозначает точность при сравнении дробных чисел. Если модуль разницы двух таких чисел меньше e, то они считаются равными. Аналогичный пример кода, если бы числа в коде были типа int:

```
 if (xx == x && yy == y) break;
```